# Если загрузить дубликат приложения в google play market, будут ли проблемы?

Tags: android, google-play

Если написать одно приложение с разными именами пакетов и выложить их в google play   c разных аккаунтов, могут ли заблокировать приложения за дубликат?

Comment: Был случай, когда настоящего автора приложения забанили просто за то, что он в Крыму, а многочисленные дубликаты его приложения со встроенной рекламой (в оригинале рекламы не было) живут до сих пор :(

Answer (score -1):

Прочитав по вашей проблеме все доступные вопросы на enSO и в сети, я пришел к умозаключению что у вас не должно быть проблем если вы будете использовать разные ключи при подписывании ваших приложений. Но с учетом того что вы можете использовать только один ключ для подписи, то вас культурно уведомят, что приложение с такой подписью уже существует. Дело не в том как вы назвали ваш пакет, а в том что вы выгружаете на маркет. Вероятнее всего, вы можете использовать два акк, и два разных ключа, и тогда у вас будет потеря 50$ куча головной боли, но в итоге у вас будет два одинаковых приложения на маркете. Я надеюсь я ответил на ваш вопрос, и мое мнение правильное по поводу вашего вопроса. Удачи в дальнейших разработках.

P.S. Мое мнение может быть ошибочным, так как я на данный момент ознакомился с документацией, и опыта в публикации приложений на маркете у меня пока нету. Чтобы быть уверенным в моем ответе мне нужно самому протестировать то что вы спрашиваете. Возможно вам скажут диаметрально противоположные вещи.

P.P.S. За все время изучения вопроса публикации на маркете я пришел к выводу что там нету четкой системы блокировки, как например в том случае который приведен в комментарии под вашим вопросом. Поэтому я бы вам советовал быть осторожнее с такими попытками.